# Attachment via NSAttributedStringKey is not visible

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, nstextattachment

The new large title feature can be customised via `largeTitleTextAttributes` which is *(like any other attributes)* a `dictionary` with `NSAttributedStringKey` keys. One of these keys is `NSAttachmentAttributeName`/`attachment`.

*Consider this:*

```
let attachment = NSTextAttachment()
attachment.image = UIImage(named: "foo")
attachment.bounds = CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: 20.0, height: 20.0)

var largeTitleTextAttributes: [NSAttributedStringKey: Any] = [:]
largeTitleTextAttributes[.attachment] = attachment
navigationBar.largeTitleTextAttributes = largeTitleTextAttributes
```

> The problem is the attachment I assigned to the `largeTitleTextAttributes` attribute `attachment` **is not visible**.

**How to add an attachment into an attributes dictionary so the attachment will be visible?** *(I'm not looking for the `NSAttributedString`'s `init(attachment: NSTextAttachment`)*

Comment: Just to be sure, have you set the prefersLargeTitle property of navigation bar to true?

Comment: Thank you for the comment - I did, but it is just an example of the way I'm trying to achieve the attachment in the attributed string. The problem is not limited to this specific case (attributes of the navigation's large title). That is the reason I chose the generic title.

Comment: You are welcome, I understand. I ask for that because your code to add the attachment to the dictionary is correct.

Answer (score 1):

AS Apple's Doc said  you can only specifiy

> You can specify the font, text color, text shadow color, and text
>   shadow offset for the title in the text attributes dictionary, using
>   the text attribute keys described in NSAttributedStringKey.

But you can directly set UILabel to title view of navigation bar like 
using following code

```
let image1Attachment = NSTextAttachment()
        image1Attachment.image = UIImage(named: "bb")
        image1Attachment.bounds = CGRect.init(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: 20, height: 20)
        let image1String = NSAttributedString(attachment: image1Attachment)
        let label: UILabel = UILabel.init(frame: (self.navigationController?.navigationBar.frame)!)
        label.attributedText = image1String
        if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
            self.navigationItem.titleView = label
            }
        else {
            // Fallback on earlier versions
        }
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your A, but that is what @Dave already said and I do not looking for a solution with `init(attachment: NSTextAttachment)` I specify in the last sentence of the question, I know this works. But the Q is - you cannot assigned `attachment` to an attachment through the attribute, why is it there then.

Answer (score 0):

From looking at Apple's Docs, the list of attributes you can specify in titleTextAttributess seems limited:

> You can specify the font, text color, text shadow color, and text
>   shadow offset for the title in the text attributes dictionary, using
>   the text attribute keys described in NSAttributedStringKey.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uinavigationbar/1624953-titletextattributes

Sadly, image attachments isn't on the list.

Comment: Good point, it is just an example of the way I'm trying to achieve the attachment in the attributed string. What about e.g. `UILabel`'s attributes